# add/remove active class on parent element when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some issues with my javascript - trying to get this to work.

To begin with, here is what I am wanting this to do:

`1.)` Add/Remove 'active' class to parent element on click

`2.)` When on child element, any clicking inside child element makes it close - Need help to make it NOT do that...if any clicking is going on inside the child element, it needs to stay open and not close up...

`3.)` Besides clicking on the parent element to open/close the child element, is there a way to allow clicking anywhere on the page to close the child element rather than only clicking on the parent element to close the child element up?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#logsterIn_profile").click(function () {
        $(".logsterIn_profile").slideToggle('200');
        $("#logsterIn_profile").addClass('active');
    });
});
```

To see what i currently have in action, [FIDDLE ME DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AzSXL/2/)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, all of this is possible. Gimme a moment to construct a fiddle.

Comment: Or not cause you found your answer. Well done @user3043124

Comment: Thanks for the interest in helping Nicholas -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the div to open AND close when the user clicks outside the parent div, or just close?

By your description, you sound like you only want the div to close, but not open if the user clicks outside.  If that's the case, you need to check if the child is open or closed when the user clicks outside of the parent, as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("html").click(function(e) {
        if (e.target == document.getElementById("logsterIn_profile")){
            $(".logsterIn_profile").slideToggle('200');
            $("#logsterIn_profile").toggleClass('active');
        }else{
            if($("#logsterIn_profile").hasClass('active')){
                $(".logsterIn_profile").slideToggle('200');
                $("#logsterIn_profile").toggleClass('active');
            }
        }
    });

    $(".logsterIn_profile").click(function( event ) {
       event.stopPropagation();
     });

});
```

You can check it out at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnny7/1/)

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what i needed.  I ended up running into 1 small snag on the one I selected as correct, but this one suits everything - Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer to all three points:

http://jsfiddle.net/vnny7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("html").click(function () {
        $(".logsterIn_profile").slideToggle('200');
        $("#logsterIn_profile").toggleClass('active');
    });
   $(".logsterIn_profile").click(function( event ) {
        event.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

1. use toggleClass to go between "active" and ""
2. use stopPropagation on the child element to put the click event on it, and stop it from "propagating" the event up to its parent
3. to get a click anywhere on the page to open/close the child, just have the click event tied to "html"

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/AzSXL/8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#logsterIn_profile").click(function () {
    $("#logsterIn_profile").toggleClass('active');
    $(".logsterIn_profile").slideToggle('200');
});
$(".logsterIn_profile").bind('click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();   
});
$("html").click(function () {
    $("#logsterIn_profile").toggleClass('active');
    $(".logsterIn_profile").slideToggle('200');
}
});
```